# Heroku deployed failed for springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

Try to deploy the spring-boot application in Heroku cloud, getting error failed to compile java app, but this is working fine in my local machine.

```
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project smartcontactmanager: Compilation failure
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_f6591bb6/src/main/java/com/smart/config/CustomUserDetails.java:[29,28] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR]   symbol:   method of(org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority)
       [ERROR]   location: interface java.util.List
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: If this working fine in your system then can you try once looking at files that are tracked by git? It might happen that you missed pushing one file to heroku.

Comment: All files working fine, not getting why I am getting error

Comment: If it's failing to compile then either it might be some dependency problem or some file might not be pushed to Heroku. Can you try once `git diff heroku/master` and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Got the solution to the above issue, problem in return the list

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running on the default JDK (`OpenJDK 8`) but your code uses `List.of`, added later (Java 9).

[Set the desired Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions) version in the `system.properties` file, located in the root of your project

```
java.runtime.version=9
```